# Can someone please explain why this doesn't work? sometimes I get nil

Tags: ruby

So I'm going through these practice problems and maybe there's a better way to do this but this is what I got. I am severely confused why this only seems to work sometimes...

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
bigs = []

arr.each do |num|
    if num > arr[idx]
      bigs << num
    end
end

sorted = bigs.sort
    if sorted.length > 1
      sorted = sorted[0]
    end

return arr.index(sorted)
end

puts nearest_larger([2, 3, 4, 8], 2) #DOES NOT WORK
puts nearest_larger([2, 3, 4, 8], 2) #DOES WORK
puts nearest_larger([8, 8, 4, 2], 2) #ALSO WORKS... why?!!!
```

Comment: We cannot help if you do not tell us what you are trying to do. Please edit to describe in words, at the beginning, the problem you are attempting to solve. Your description of the problem needs to be complete and precise.

Comment: the purpose is to find the nearest larger number that occurs in the array.

Comment: What is there is no larger number? What if `arr = [10, 3, 2]` and `idx = 1`. Then the only larger number is `10` so that's what you want. Correct? What about `[10, 3, 10]` and `idx = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what this function is supposed to do as I don't know the exercises you're doing, but the most obvious issue I'm seeing is that you are sometimes checking an array for another array, and sometimes checking it for the actual element. The suspect block in particular is the the `if sorted.length > 1; sorted = sorted[0]; end`.

In your first call that does not work, there is only one number that is greater than index `2`, which is 8. `sorted` in this case will only have a length of `1` - so it's not changing it from an array to the first item due to your if statement.

By all means, the second case should not work either.

A slightly modified working version of your code would be as follows.

```rb
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  larger_numbers = []

  arr.each do |num|
    if num > arr[idx]
      larger_numbers << num
    end
  end

  smallest_larger_number = larger_numbers.sort()[0]

  return arr.index(smallest_larger_number)
end
```

A smaller version would like this:

```rb
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  arr.index(arr.select {|num| num > arr[idx]}.sort()[0])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an array `a` and an array index `i`, suppose `idxa` is an array of indices `j` of `a` for which `a[j] > a[i]`. If `idxa` is empty `nil` is to be returned; else the problem is find an index `k` in `idxa` for which `(k-i).abs` is a minimum. If `idx` contains more than one index `k` for which `(k-i).abs` is a minimum any of those indices may be returned.

**Select indices and find closest**

Here is a simple but not especially efficient way of solving the problem.

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  v = arr[idx]
  a = arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i] > v }
  return nil if a.empty?
  a.min_by { |i| (i-idx).abs }
end

test = [
  [[2, 3, 4, 8], 2],
  [[8, 5, 4, 3], 2],
  [[8, 3, 4, 2], 2],
  [[8, 5, 8, 2], 2]
]

test.each do |arr, idx|
  i = nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  puts "#{arr} idx = #{idx}: closest idx = #{i.nil? ? "nil" : i}"
end
[2, 3, 4, 8] idx = 2: closest idx = 3
[8, 5, 4, 3] idx = 2: closest idx = 1
[8, 3, 4, 2] idx = 2: closest idx = 0
[8, 5, 8, 2] idx = 2: closest idx = nil
```

Let's examine the steps for these values of `arr` and `idx`:

```
arr = [8, 5, 4, 3]
idx = 2
```

```
v = arr[idx]
  #=> 4 
e = arr.each_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [8, 5, 4, 3]:each_index>
```

As you see the method [Array#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each_index), when invoked on `arr` returns an enumerator. Think of that as a machine that generates values. We can convert enumerators to arrays to see what values they will generate:

```
e.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Continuing,

```
a = e.select { |i| arr[i] > v }
  #=> [0, 1]
```

`e` passes elements to [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-select) which in turn passes then to the block, assigning the block variable `i` to their values. In fact, we could write

```
ee = e.select
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [8, 5, 4, 3]:each_index>:select> 
ee.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
a = ee.each { |i| arr[i] > v }
  #=> [0, 1]
```

`ee` can be thought of as a *compound* enumerator. If this last bit is confusing forget it for now.

Continuing,

```
return nil if a.empty?
```

`a` is not empty so we do not return. The last step is the following.

```
a.min_by { |i| (i-idx).abs }
  #=> 1
```

See [Enumerable#min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by).

Note that I could have replaced `arr.each_index` with `arr.size.times` (see [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-times)) or with `0.up_to(arr.size-1)` (see [Integer#upto](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-upto)).

**Check either side then move out by one until a larger value is found**

We can improve efficiency at the expense of increased complexity. In fact, the following code is not very Ruby-like and imo rather unattractive.

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  v = arr[idx]
  last = arr.size-1
  iup, idn = idx + 1, idx - 1
  while iup <= last || idn >= 0
    if iup <= last
      return iup if arr[iup] > v
      iup += 1
    end
    if idn >= 0
      return idn if arr[idn] > v
      idn -= 1
    end
  end
  nil
end

test.each do |arr, idx|
  i = nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  puts "#{arr} idx = #{idx}: closest idx = #{i.nil? ? "nil" : i}"
end
[2, 3, 4, 8] idx = 2: closest idx = 3
[8, 5, 4, 3] idx = 2: closest idx = 1
[8, 3, 4, 2] idx = 2: closest idx = 0
[8, 5, 8, 2] idx = 2: closest idx = nil
```